# Snowflake REGEX to identify if column contains a new line character and print Line 1

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column where it contains data as below:

"abc\nxyz 123"

Want to identify the new line and print just abc as my output query.

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_SUBSTR

```
select $1 as val,
    regexp_substr(val, '([^(\\\\n)]*)\\\\n',1,1,'e',1) as r1
from values
('abc\\ncde\\nefg\\nxyz 3'),
('abc\\ncde\\nxyz 2'),
('abc\\nxyz 1'),
('abcxyz 0');
```

| VAL | R1 |
| --- | --- |
| abc\ncde\nefg\nxyz 3 | abc |
| abc\ncde\nxyz 2 | abc |
| abc\nxyz 1 | abc |
| abcxyz 0 |  |

Comment: Any idea, why do i get the regexp_count(COL1,'\\n') as '0' even though the COL1field has '\n' ? And this field is really huge with multiple sentences in it. And the data type of this field is TEXT.

Comment: the problem is I do not know "how you got that exactly" anyways, if your REGEXP is in a stored process, you might have to escape the escaping, thus use `regexp_count(COL1,'\\\\n')`

Comment: I am using the REGEXP in the query in snowflake UI. And regexp_count(COL1,'\\\\n') worked. One more thing please, how do I extract the text before '\n'. I mean line 1 in the text

Comment: if you are typing `regexp_count(COL1,'\\\\n') ` into the UI you do not have a newline character in your data, you have two character tokens, one being a slash, and the other being a n

Comment: Ah, see I missed-read the "and print line 1" as "print the value 1"